# What are all these pins on the DS1307 RTC for?

Tags: arduino, clock, rtc

I recently ordered a DS1307 RTC from ebay. Before, I did some research and found out that you only need 4 pins for it: Vcc, GND, SDA, and SCL. The one I got has many other pins like DS, BAT, SQ(I read that this one is optional). It also has 2 DS pins, 2 SCL, 2 SDA, 2 VCC, and 2 GND. Can I still use this one with 4 pins? I am a beginner at electronics so a simple answer would be appreciated. I also read something about a temperature sensor - maybe some of the pins are for it. Which SCL, SDA, GND, and VCC pin do I use out of the two? Here is the link to ebay: [link.](http://www.ebay.com/itm/281943128978?_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT) Here is a picture of the module: [image]

Comment: Do you have a link to a datasheet, or to the seller's page?

Comment: Here it is: http://www.ebay.com/itm/281943128978?_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT

Comment: Can you test for continuity between the pins in the left (DS, SCL, SDA, etc.) and the pins in the right with the same name? I would say that they're connected to the same net; so it makes no difference which one you use.

Comment: You should put that link in your question.  However, I don't see any mention of documentation there.  You should ask the vendor for documentation since the board is more than just a DS1307 - no documentation = don't buy!.  You should also look for the DS1307 datasheet (and link it in your question) - it may provide some useful information.

Comment: @RogerC. You are absolutely right. They are connected. Can you explain what DS and BAT is for? Those are the ones not mentioned anywhere.

Comment: I guess that BAT is connected to the plus terminal of the battery in the back of the board. It might provide a means to check its voltage.

Comment: To know what DS is you can look for continuity between this pin and the different pins of both ICs (probing directly on the IC's pins).

Comment: The caption at the link says: "For Arduino AVR ARM PIC 51 New RTC I2C DS1307 AT24C32 Real Time Clock Module". This is a dedicated module pre-wired for Arduino over an I2C buss. This is a module, not just an IC. Could not find schematic. Some pins are obvious, some are not.

Comment: @NickSolonko, found the answer here http://www.hobbyist.co.nz/?q=real_time_clock . DS is supposed to interface with a DS18B20 temperature sensor. I don't know if this component is indeed in your board or this pin is just there for header compatibility between modules.

Comment: Nick, get into a habit of reading datasheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: in a well done board, if a label in the silkscreen is the same in different places of the board then it belongs to the same net; i.e. SDA in the left is connected to the SDA in the right, etc. You might want of course to check this with a multimeter.

This particular board has two ICs hanging from the same I2C bus: a DS1037 (RTC) and a AT24C32 (an EEPROM). Then the board itself simply connects the pins of the ICs to the header pins of the board, plus a crystal, some passive components and a backup battery.